# Import Data From Google API to Parse

Tags: json, rest, import, parse-platform, google-places-api

I am trying to import all restaurant data (within a certain location) from Google Places API to a Parse class. What is the best approach?
*The types of data I need are: name, opening_hours (array), price, geometry (location), etc.*

1. Do I need to download all the Google Places data first and then import it into Parse or can this be done all at once?
2. Parse supports "REST" API, should I be using REST or import through json/csv?
3. **How do I go about "retrieving" the Google data? (trying to wrap my head around the concept)**

   - Google API -https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details
   - Parse Import API -https://www.parse.com/docs/data#data-import
   - Parse REST API -https://parse.com/docs/rest

Sorry for the newbie questions. I've never migrated data using API before.

Comment: I have dealt with this issue before, but never got passed it... In my opinion, your going to have to download all the data from the api, format it in a csv, and import the data... Typically the simplest but most annoying way

Comment: As for accessing the api... it seems like your first step needs to be getting an API key... Then deciding what format you want to receive the data in 'xml or son', i'd perfer json... Then specifying what parameters you want the user or yourself to query the api against.

Comment: Or instead of having to manually deal with importing the data into Parse... You can just query the API for events that you or the user wants, then once the client whats to view more detail of the event, just save the event as a PFObject with a unique identifier (other than objectId, maybe the name of the event) and all the fields the event has that you want to have in your database and store it. Once the object is saved, you can request to attend (or set going) or add attributes for the event (comment/like) ... Sorry, this is probably very poorly written :P

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against storing the data in a Parse class. The Google Places API is there for the ever-changing data that is out there on restaurants. If you import it into Parse, you would have to constantly update it. The Google Places API is fantastic and easy to use. Currently I use it in my AngularJS application for an autocomplete text input. I also use the Google Geocoding API in my Cloud Code with a Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest. Both work great but I would never want to import the API data and make it static...

I think a better option is like @jsetting32 commented about. Query the API for the events in the area, then save the one the user selects in a ParseObject. You can pick and choose the data you want to save and even give it start and end dates so users can look at past events.